# how to remove custom words in list using the last character in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, nlp, python-re

I have data like this:

```
lst = [['name','address','addressgmailcom'],['name','address','namegmailcom']]
```

Here need to remove 'addressgmailcom' and 'namegmailcom' using 'gmailcom' or last characters.

My list only contain name, address

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove last elements from your list elements you can try:

```
[el[:-1] for el in lst]
```

The result will be:

```
[['name', 'address'], ['name', 'address']]
```